# TypeError: create_superuser() missing 3 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, django, typeerror, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

Got the following error when I try to create new superuser using terminal.

```
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'location'
```

I followed another stackoverflow page , in comments below. In that page it insisted to create a create_superuser function with `user.save(using=self._db)`
Still this code have bugs,

**How to use 'first_name', 'last_name', and 'location' without providing any default values to them.**

first_name , last_name and location are CharField with max_length = 30 and it can have blank values.

In this custom-user-model the username is replaced with mobile_no by making it as unique in the User class.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
        AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager,PermissionsMixin
    )
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # All required field must be passed below as argument
    def create_user(self, mobile_no, role, email, first_name, last_name, location, password=None, is_active=True,is_staff=False, is_admin= False):
        if not mobile_no:
            raise ValueError("User must have an Mobile number as username ")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj= self.model(
            mobile_no= mobile_no
        )
        user_obj.email = email
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.role = role
        user_obj.first_name = first_name
        user_obj.las_name = last_name
        user_obj.is_active = is_active
        user_obj.location = location
        user_obj.is_staff = is_staff
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_superuser(self, mobile_no, role, email, first_name, last_name, location, password=None, is_active=True,is_staff=False, is_admin= False):
        user_obj= self.model(
            mobile_no=mobile_no
        )
        user_obj.email = email
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.role = role
        user_obj.first_name = first_name
        user_obj.las_name = last_name
        user_obj.location = location
        user_obj.is_staff = True
        user_obj.is_admin = True
        user_obj.is_active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self, mobile_no, role, email, first_name, last_name, location, password=None, is_active=True,is_staff=False, is_admin= False):
        user_obj= self.model(
            mobile_no=mobile_no
        )
        user_obj.email = email
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.role = role
        user_obj.first_name = first_name
        user_obj.las_name = last_name
        user_obj.location = location
        user_obj.is_staff = True
        user_obj.is_admin = False
        user_obj.is_active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
        return user_obj


    # def get_by_natural_key(self, mobile_no_):
    #     print(mobile_no_)
    #     return self.get(mobile_no=mobile_no_)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    mobile_no   = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    role        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile_no'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'role']

    objects= UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.mobile_no

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mobile_no

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: in your create superuser, `first_name`, `last_name`, and `location` are all required parameters.  If you want them optional, provide a default value as you have with `password`, `is_active`, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: create\_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'profile\_picture'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474632/typeerror-create-superuser-missing-1-required-positional-argument-profile-p)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with createsuperuser when implementing custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239164/issue-with-createsuperuser-when-implementing-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works for the above case

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, mobile_no, role, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not mobile_no:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an Mobile No')

        user = self.model(
            mobile_no=mobile_no,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.activated=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, mobile_no, role, password):
        """
         Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(mobile_no, role=role,
                                password=password
                                )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.activated=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, mobile_no, role, password):
        """
         Creates and saves a staffuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(mobile_no, role=role,
                                password=password
                                )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.activated=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
class Users(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    object = UserManager()
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(_('MobNumber'), null=True, blank=True,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email'), max_length=75, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('FirstName'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('LastName'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(_('Role'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(_('Location'), max_length=70, null=True, blank=True)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(_('DateTime'), auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(_('Activated'), default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(_('is_admin'), default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('is_staff'), default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.mobile_no)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mobile_no)

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile_no'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['role']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having this issue because in your required fields, you only specified email and role without the first_name, last_name, and location. When declaring the user user manager, you did not supply default values for those fields, so you have to specify them in the required field. That should solve your problem.

The credit for this answer goes to @Daniel Roseman: [Issue with createsuperuser when implementing custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239164/issue-with-createsuperuser-when-implementing-custom-user-model)