# Django create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('user must have smartcard')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('must have username')

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,

        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )
        user.is_admin =True
        user.is_staff =True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):

    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=30, unique=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DEPARTMENT)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username',]

    objects=MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email   

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

I just can't get what is wrong.

**While creating a superuser the prompt doesnt ask me for entering username**

I modified the settings.py file as well.
Tried several times with various databases. 
I have also added the username in REQUIRED_FIELDS section.

Comment: Include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with createsuperuser when implementing custom user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25239164/issue-with-createsuperuser-when-implementing-custom-user-model)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO, @Omkar.

You just need to change the fields `REQUIRED_FIELD` to `REQUIRED_FIELDS`.

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

You can check it on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS).

Answer (score 2):

**@Omkar Kale**, Please look your method:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,
        username=username,
    )
```

Please change it:

```
 def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):

    user = self.create_user(
        username=username,
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        password=password,

        )
```

Look, you need to pass value according to the parameter. So

- **first**: username,
- **second**: email
- **third** password.

Then you will no longer going to receive **error for positional argument**. you have to pass them according to the position of the parameter.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question, but is good advice in general — consistent order of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Works   perfectly after adding the REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']  while using the CustomUser model in django .I am able to  create the superuser using the terminal

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
bio = models.TextField(null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```